# How/Where to Extract Transaction Per Second in AWS EC2 & RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

First of all, I am not certain if this is the right venue for my question. Just let me know which platform/site should I go to.

Re: I have to get transaction per second both in EC2 (ubuntu) or RDS (postgres) or any equivalent for a specific time period. Are these available in AWS console? If not, are there any server logs which I can refer to or what are my options?

Comment: Define what do you mean by "transaction", if you mean number of requests, AWS has no inbuilt support, but you need to find out an agent and use that to monitor those metrics.

Comment: Yes...requests per second. I am looking into agents as a long-term solution, but for the moment I really have to extract something... probably from access logs.